# Writing a Rails scope that returns all records where two different users have sent each other a message

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on an app that has the following setup:

```rb
class Booking
  belongs_to :guest
  belongs_to :member
end
```

```rb
class Guest
  has_many :conversation_participations, as: :participant
  has_many :conversations, through: :conversation_participations
  has_many :conversation_items, as: :author
end
```

```rb
class Member
  has_many :conversation_participations, as: :participant
  has_many :conversations, through: :conversation_participations
  has_many :conversation_items, as: :author
end
```

```rb
class ConversationItem
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :author, polymorphic: true
end
```

```rb
class Conversation
  has_many :conversation_items
  has_many :conversation_participations
  has_many :participant_guests,
           through: :conversation_participations,
           source: :participant,
           source_type: 'Guest'
  has_many :participant_members,
           through: :conversation_participations,
           source: :participant,
           source_type: 'Member'
end
```

```rb
class ConversationParticipation
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :participant, polymorphic: true
end
```

I've been tasked with writing a scope within `Booking` that returns every booking for which the guest has sent a message (a conversation item) to the member **and** the member has sent a message to the guest.

Typically I write scopes with ActiveRecord, but I haven't been able to come up with a way to do that here, primarily because I've been unable to get the guest/member ID from the booking.

I think this is too complex to write in a single query, so I've been trying to break it down, so for example within `Member` I want a scope that returns all members that have sent a message to the guest, for example I'm thinking something like:

```rb
class Member
  ...
  scope :has_sent_message_to_guest, -> (guest) { joins(conversation_items: { conversation: :participant_members }).where(participant_members: { id: [guest.id] }) }
end
```

That doesn't work, but it's along the lines of what I'm trying to do. Then if I could write a similar scope on `Guest`, I could then call these from the booking, chaining them together to return the bookings I need.

I feel a bit out of my depth with this. I'm not especially proficient when it comes to writing pure SQL, and this feels too complex to do with ActiveRecord, so a big thanks to anyone who can help me solve this.

Comment: It looks like you're really overcomplicating this. If a booking has a single guest and member why is it that you think you need all these layers of join tables? Also I would really use two different join tables instead of a single table with a polymorphic assocation as its a huge compromise in terms of referential integrity.

Comment: Interesting! I tend to think that you could come up with something just in `Booking`. but I need to think a bit about it Just to see how it works, have you tried querying with raw SQL from `Booking`, and then see how you can move pieces across different layers?

Comment: @Pipetus No, I'm fairly green at writing pure SQL; I do the majority of my queries with ActiveRecord, I just don't think that's possible here. I'm going to have to get my head into a course on SQL to try and figure it out, because I think you're probably right; it can be done from `Booking`, I'm just struggling with taking the Guest/Member IDs from the booking and using them in the latter part of the query on conversations.

Comment: @max Agree with you about the two join tables, but it's a database I inherited, and updating the relationships is beyond the scope of what I'm trying to do here.

The reason for the join tables is that we need the Guest/Member IDs taken from the booking in order to query the conversations. Can you give an example of how you could do this from the booking? I don't see it.

Comment: What's the error with the scope you tried? And also, can you provide a minimal gist 
with your actual code or something so as we can copy and try locally? I guess you could be missing something in the above code that could be important.